# Magento configswatches Call to a member function toOptionArray() on a non-object

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, configurable-product, ce-1.9.1.0

I am using Magento 1.9.1.0 when I go to **admin >catalog > configurable swatches** in admin

I get the error below:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function toOptionArray() on a non-object in app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\System\Config\Form.php on line 463

My magento version was updated from 1.9 to 1.9.1.0

I could not figure out how to fix it, based on some online research 
when I comment below text from file
**"app/code/core/Mage/ConfigurableSwatches/etc/system.xml"**

it works fine

commented text :

```
                <swatch_attributes translate="label">
                    <label>Product Attributes to Show as Swatches in Product Detail</label>
                    <frontend_type>multiselect</frontend_type>
                    <source_model>configurableswatches/system_config_source_catalog_product_configattribute</source_model>
                    <sort_order>20</sort_order>
                    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                    <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                    <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                    <can_be_empty>1</can_be_empty>
                </swatch_attributes>
                <product_list_attribute translate="label">
                    <label>Product Attribute to Use for Swatches in Product Listing</label>
                    <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                    <source_model>configurableswatches/system_config_source_catalog_product_configattribute_select</source_model>
                    <sort_order>30</sort_order>
                    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                    <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                    <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                </product_list_attribute>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That means, the **source model** for these form fields could not be loaded. Check if the following files are present and readable:

- `app/code/core/Mage/ConfigurableSwatches/Model/System/Config/Source/Catalog/Product/Configattribute.php`
- `app/code/core/Mage/ConfigurableSwatches/Model/System/Config/Source/Catalog/Product/Configattribute/Select.php`

Answer (score 0):

Hate the 50 points to comment. 
Anyway tx to fschmengler.
Looked and said file was .ph and not .php
Why? Haven't a clue as the file isn't that way from Magento.
I have re-downloaded and uploaded new a few times. Each time it had this error.
Now gone. yeah

Just a bit more on MY finding. 
Did a search and found about 45-50 files that end in .ph and not .php. Checked the source file from Magento and it is .php. Said files have been both FTP directly and also unzipped on the server itself. Looking into WHY/How they get changed to .ph. The ONYL other thing I found online about .ph is from 2007 for Zen-Cart. Oddly persons server also had webshell...

Comment: This would probably be better as a separate question, too long for a comment anyway ;) Wild guess: these files reached the maximum path length of the file system and the names were cut off.